# How are lists implemented in Haskell (GHC)?

Tags: haskell, linked-list, ghc

I was just curious about some exact implementation details of lists in Haskell (GHC-specific answers are fine)--are they naive linked lists, or do they have any special optimizations?  More specifically:

1. Do `length` and `(!!)` (for instance) have to iterate through the list?
2. If so, are their values cached in any way (i.e., if I call `length` twice, will it have to iterate both times)?
3. Does access to the back of the list involve iterating through the whole list?
4. Are infinite lists and list comprehensions memoized?  (i.e., for `fib = 1:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)`, will each value be computed recursively, or will it rely on the previous computed value?)

Any other interesting implementation details would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haskell also has [arrays](https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrays) and ["mutable arrays"](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Lists have no special operational treatment in Haskell.  They are defined just like:

```
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
```

Just with some special notation: `[a]` for `List a`, `[]` for `Nil` and `(:)` for `Cons`.  If you defined the same and redefined all the operations, you would get the exact same performance.

Thus, Haskell lists are singly-linked.  Because of laziness, they are often used as iterators.  `sum [1..n]` runs in constant space, because the unused prefixes of this list are garbage collected as the sum progresses, and the tails aren't generated until they are needed.

As for #4: *all* values in Haskell are memoized, with the exception that functions do not keep a memo table for their arguments.  So when you define `fib` like you did, the results will be cached and the nth fibonacci number will be accessed in O(n) time.  However, if you defined it in this apparently equivalent way:

```
-- Simulate infinite lists as functions from Integer
type List a = Int -> a

cons :: a -> List a -> List a
cons x xs n | n == 0    = x
            | otherwise = xs (n-1)

tailF :: List a -> List a
tailF xs n = xs (n+1)

fib :: List Integer
fib = 1 `cons` (1 `cons` (\n -> fib n + tailF fib n))
```

(Take a moment to note the similarity to your definition)

Then the results are not shared and the nth fibonacci number will be accessed in O(fib n) (which is exponential) time.  You can convince functions to be shared with a memoization library like [data-memocombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-memocombinators).

Comment: Can someone please clarify what is meant by "functions do not keep a memo table for their arguments"? This post seems to be saying that if you defined lists yourself, you'd get the same performance -- then ends by saying that if you actually did that, you would NOT get the same performance. What's the difference?

Comment: @nupanick, the difference is that the example definition uses `Int -> a` (a function) as a model for lists, so it is not memoized. If you defined list yourself in the usual way: `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)` then memoization would occur. Basically, the only thing that *doesn't* get remembered is if you call `f 1` and later call `f 1` again.  Distinct function applications (even to the same argument) will be recomputed.

Answer (score 13):

As far as I know (I don't know how much of this is GHC-specific)

1. `length` and `(!!)` DO have to iterate through the list.
2. I don't think there are any special optimisations for lists, but there is a technique that applies to all datatypes.

   If you have something like

   ```
   foo xs = bar (length xs) ++ baz (length xs)
   ```

   then `length xs` will be computed twice.

   But if instead you have

   ```
   foo xs = bar len ++ baz len
     where len = length xs
   ```

   then it will only be computed once.
3. Yes.
4. Yes, once part of a named value is computed, it is retained until the name goes out of scope.
   (The language doesn't require this, but this is how I understand the implementations behave.)

Comment: For 2., I meant if I have `doubleLength xs = length xs + length xs` (contrived, I know), will it compute length both times?

Comment: @eman: see edit. I think it will only compute it once. I'm sure someone more knowledgeable will be along soon to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: GHC does not do common subexpression elimination by default.  This is because it can be catastrophic in some cases, for example:  sum [1..10^6] / fromIntegral (length [1..10^6]), if [1..10^6] were shared here then this computation would take 8 MB and take a long time because GC load.  Here it is much better to recompute the list than to share it.  But you are correct that if you name it -- eg. let len = length xs in bar len ++ baz len -- then it will be shared.  This isn't in the standard, just GHC and every other reasonable compiler. :-)

Comment: @luqui: so in that case, it would compute `length xs` both times unless you have a named expression?

Comment: @eman, in your example, yes.  GHC might be able to tell that sharing an expression of type int couldn't possibly leak, but I don't think it does.

Answer (score 11):

> If so, are their values cached in any way (i.e., if I call length  twice, will it have to iterate both times)?

[GHC does not perform full Common Subexpression Elimination](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC#Common_subexpressions). For example:

```
{-# NOINLINE aaaaaaaaa #-}
aaaaaaaaa :: [a] -> Int
aaaaaaaaa x = length x + length x

{-# NOINLINE bbbbbbbbb #-}
bbbbbbbbb :: [a] -> Int
bbbbbbbbb x = l + l where l = length x

main = bbbbbbbbb [1..2000000] `seq` aaaaaaaaa [1..2000000] `seq` return ()
```

Gives on `-ddump-simpl`:

```
Main.aaaaaaaaa [NEVER Nothing] :: forall a_adp.
                                  [a_adp] -> GHC.Types.Int
GblId
[Arity 1
 NoCafRefs
 Str: DmdType Sm]
Main.aaaaaaaaa =
  \ (@ a_ahc) (x_adq :: [a_ahc]) ->
    case GHC.List.$wlen @ a_ahc x_adq 0 of ww_anf { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.List.$wlen @ a_ahc x_adq 0 of ww1_Xnw { __DEFAULT ->
    GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.+# ww_anf ww1_Xnw)
    }
    }

Main.bbbbbbbbb [NEVER Nothing] :: forall a_ado.
                                  [a_ado] -> GHC.Types.Int
GblId
[Arity 1
 NoCafRefs
 Str: DmdType Sm]
Main.bbbbbbbbb =
  \ (@ a_adE) (x_adr :: [a_adE]) ->
    case GHC.List.$wlen @ a_adE x_adr 0 of ww_anf { __DEFAULT ->
    GHC.Types.I# (GHC.Prim.+# ww_anf ww_anf)
    }
```

Note that `aaaaaaaaa` calls `GHC.List.$wlen` twice.

(In fact, because `x` needs to be retained in `aaaaaaaaa`, it is more than 2x slower than `bbbbbbbbb`.)